JSON Schema - reusing base/root attributes in nested objects
So I have the following JSON structure:
{
  "attributeA": "...",
  "attributeB": "...",
  "attributeC": "...",
  "attributeD": "...",
  "innerObjA": {
    "attributeA": "...",
    "attributeB": "...",
    "attributeC": "...",
    "exclusiveFieldX": "...",
  },
  "innerObjB": {
    "attributeA": "...",
    "attributeB": "...",
    "attributeC": "...",
    "exclusiveFieldY": "..."
  }
}

and I am trying to build up a JSON Schema to validate the structure.
As of now I have something like this:
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
    "title": "Product",
    "description": "A product in the catalog",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "attributeA": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "attributeB": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "attributeC": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "attributeD": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "innerObjA": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "attributeA": {
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "attributeB": {
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "attributeC": {
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "exclusiveFieldX": {
                    "type": "String"
                }
            }
        },
        "innerObjB": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "attributeA": {
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "attributeB": {
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "attributeC": {
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "exclusiveFieldY": {
                    "type": "String"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "common_inner_fields": {}
    }
}

and I believe the "common_inner_fields" can be used to store the 3 common fields like this:
    "$defs": {
        "base_properties_platform": {
            "attributeA": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "attributeB": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "attributeC": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    }

but I don't know if it's possible to sort of combine that with the exclusive fields:
        "innerObjA": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "$ref": "#/$defs/base_properties_platform",
                "exclusiveFieldX": {
                    "type": "String"
                }
            }
        },
        "innerObjB": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "$ref": "#/$defs/base_properties_platform",
                "exclusiveFieldY": {
                    "type": "String"
                }
            }
        }


How can I achieve such combination?

You're on the right track, one thing you need to consider is the draft version of JSON Schema being used. Some of the behavior changed over time.
I see your example is using draft2020-12, so I'll focus on that one but provide earlier behavior for completeness
JSON Schema draft-2020-12
$refs can have sibling definitions at any level, so it's just a matter of defining the $ref and the additional properties definition.
In your example, you have the $ref inside the properties definition, it should be a sibling to properties.
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
    "title": "Product",
    "description": "A product in the catalog",
    "$ref": "#/$defs/base_properties_platform",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "attributeD": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "innerObjA": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/base_properties_platform",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "exclusiveFieldX": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "innerObjB": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/base_properties_platform",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "exclusiveFieldY": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "base_properties_platform": {
            "attributeA": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "attributeB": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "attributeC": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}

JSON Schema draft-04 - present
The previous drafts required the use of allOf to encapsulate the $ref and properties definition because prior to draft-2020-12, siblings were not allowed with $ref. The spec remains backwards compatible to use this design if you are migrating from older versions.
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
    "title": "Product",
    "description": "A product in the catalog",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/base_properties_platform"
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "attributeD": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "innerObjA": {
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/base_properties_platform"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "exclusiveFieldX": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "innerObjB": {
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/base_properties_platform"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "exclusiveFieldY": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "base_properties_platform": {
            "attributeA": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "attributeB": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "attributeC": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}


p.s. JSON Schema primitive types are always lowercase. string, object, array, number, integer, boolean, null
